# Android: access SharedPrefernces from non-activity class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I was trying to access SharedPrefernces from non-activity class.

I was trying to do it in this way:

```
Context applicationContext = MainActivity.getContextOfApplication();
SharedPreferences prefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
private int age = prefs.getInt("Age", 0);
private String name = prefs.getString("Name", null);
```

But variable age is 0, and variable name is null.

What am I doing wrong?

I save SharedPreferences in activity class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.saveButton:
            saveText();
            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            int age = prefs.getInt("Age", 0);
            String name = prefs.getString("Name", null);
            if(name == null || age <= 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(NameAge.this, "Put your name and your age", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(NameAge.this, age+prefs.getString("Name", 
                           null), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(NameAge.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                break;
            }
    }
}

private void saveText()
{
    prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString(NAME, nameText.getText().toString());
    ed.putInt(AGE, Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString()));
    ed.commit();

}
```

Comment: In your save text, what is the value of NAME and AGE Keys?

Comment: use the same key in your nonactivity class also , i.e. : `private int age = prefs.getInt("AGE", 0);
private String name = prefs.getString("NAME", null);`

Comment: Agree with @SamarthKejriwal. When you store/get values from preferences always keep the same key value. (It's case sensitive).

Comment: i think in getPreferences need two parameter like getPreferences("string argument",MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: So when you put your shared preference in save text you use key as NAME which would have some value. whereas when you use this you use key as "Name". If the NAME is not  sam as "Name" your default values will get selected which are null and 0. Make sure keys match at both places

Comment: @kapsym they are the same. NAME is a final string "Name". same with AGE.

Comment: make changes that @aditi did it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to get preference from default shared preference file while you have stored prefernce at activity context level using  `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)`.

If you store preference like below it will work

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString(NAME, nameText.getText().toString());
    ed.putInt(AGE, Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString()));
    ed.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString("name", "abc").commit();
    ed.putInt("age", 5).commit();
     int age = prefs.getInt("Age", 0);
     String name = prefs.getString("Name", null);
```

If I use the above code same issue happens 0 and null value with the code in activity. Try using

```
prefs= getSharedPreferences("userPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

instead of defaultSharedPreference.